# Custom text color for certain indexes in QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I would like to draw texts in one of the columns in a QTreeView widget using a custom color (depending on the data related to each row). I tried to overload the drawRow() protected method and change the style option parameter like this (a stripped-down example):

```
virtual void drawRow(QPainter* p_painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
                     const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    QStyleOptionViewItem optionCustom = option;
    if (index.column() == 2)
    {
        optionCustom.palette.setColor(QPalette::Text, Qt::red);
    }
    QTreeView::drawRow(p_painter, optionCustom, index);
 }
```

But obviously I am missing something because this does not seem to work (I tried to change also the `QPalette::WindowText` color role).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your model, extend the `data()` function to return a given color as the `Qt::ForegroundRole` role.

For example:

```
virtual QVariant MyModel::data( const QModelIndex &index, int role ) const
{
    if ( index.isValid() && role == Qt::ForegroundRole )
    {
        if ( index.column() == 2 )
        {
            return QVariant( QColor( Qt::red ) );
        }
        return QVariant( QColor( Qt::black ) );
    }

    return QAbstractItemModel::data( index, role );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that the `data()` method is used also for the item's appearance. I implemented what I wanted using a custom item delegate, with an overridden `paint()` method, but using the `data()` method is ever so much more elegant.

Comment: @VladoKlimovský yes but there are some purists who don't think it should be used for appearance, as they want content and appearance to be handled separately (model vs delegate).